# Pros and cons of using Behaviorsubjects for changing values

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I understood that you should use (Behavior)subjects for values that can change over time. But most of the time when I look into the source code of other projects they use primitive data types for changing values.

So my question is what are the pros and cons of using exclusively Subjects for changing values like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    template: `
        <div> 
            <div *ngIf="isLoading | async">
                <img src="loading.gif"/>
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="errorCode | async">
                An error occurred. Please try again later.
            </div>

            <ng-container *ngIf="data | async; let jobs">
                <div *ngFor="let job of jobs;">
                    {{ job.title }}
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    errorCode = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null);
    isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
    data      = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    constructor(
        public service: TestService,
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.isLoading.next(true);
        this.getData();
    }

    public getData() {
        this.service.getData().subscribe((data)=> {
            this.data.next(data);
            this.isLoading.next(false);
        }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.errorCode.next(error.status);
            this.isLoading.next(false);
        });
    }
}
```

vs using primitive data types like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    template: `
        <div> 
            <div *ngIf="isLoading">
                <img src="loading.gif"/>
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="errorCode">
                An error occurred. Please try again later.
            </div>

            <ng-container *ngIf="data; let jobs">
                <div *ngFor="let job of jobs;">
                    {{ job.title }}
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    errorCode : number | null = null;
    isLoading : boolean = true;
    data : any = null;

    constructor(
        public service: TestService,
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.getData();
    }

    public getData() {
        this.service.getData().subscribe((data)=> {
            this.data = data;
            this.isLoading = false;
        }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.errorCode = error.status;
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry for asking such a general question but this topic gives me a real hard time and i couldn't find any conclusive answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` is a pipe used for the developer's convenience.

A common *best practice* is to create *dry* components. These are components that perform no business logic but simply render a template.

You can use `async` in the template's to keep the component as *dry* as possible. It's basically a component that does nothing in its `class` and all the work is done in the template.

*Dry* components are low risk and easy to test.

The moment you start *mixing* the use of the `async` pipe with business logic in the components it starts becoming complicated. I'm not saying it's bad or wrong, but it's simply difficult to find the connection between `stuff | async` and where `stuff.next(value)` happens.

So if you have a component that has no logic, and the template uses `async` it's easy to maintain, but if you have `async` in the template and the component is doing a lot of work to create and emit values to observables it becomes difficult to maintain.

One advantage for *not* using `async` in templates is that you can hit a breakpoint in the debugger, and `this` for the component represents its current state. If you have `async` you won't know what the current values are for observables used in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Advantage: it allows using the `OnPush` strategy for the component.

Disadvantages: it's more complex, harder to understand and test, and easier to introduce bugs due to the additional complexity.

Comment: I don't understand how this would benefit `OnPush` notification? Can you explain the reasons more. I'm interested in learning what you mean. Are you referring to the host component or the template here?

Comment: OnPush tells Angular that it should only run a change detection on the component when its inputs change, or when a dom event is handled by the component. So the changes made to the component by the HTTP callback would not be detected in the second example. They would in the first one, because the state of the component doesn't actually change: new events are emitted by the observables, and the async pipes subscribe to these changes and make sure the DOM is updated when a change is emitted.

Comment: Yes I agree. I think the wording of your answer could be updated. The phrase "it allows" implies some kind of restriction otherwise. Maybe rephrase as "async supports OnPush strategies for components"

Comment: There **is** a restriction otherwise. Using OnPush wouldn't work with the second snippet.

Comment: The second snippet doesn't work because it doesn't call `markForCheck()` on the change detector. Which I think is a different topic of discussion. I just don't understand why you would phrase using observables allows you to use OnPush. You can use it anyway. The two aren't required to use either.

Comment: Using the first snippet instead of the first one does allow using OnPush. The fact that there are other ways to transform the second snippet to make OnPush work doesn't change that fact. I never said anywhere that there is no way to use OnPush without using observables and async.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points:

Pros:

1. The observables are async, thus non blocking. This means, that other tasks may be processed while the observable is waiting.
2. There may be many observers subscribing to the observable. Any of them will be informed once the data has arrived.
3. After all complex applications will be faster.
4. Asynchronous programming is already state of the art and will remain in the future.

Cons:

1. Just a bit complicated for a start.
2. Hard to test, sometimes horrible.